# Aws Eks (Kubernetes) Thingsboard setup

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, thingsboard, amazon-eks

I am trying to set up ThingsBoard in AWS EKS ( Kubernetes) as a individual micro service, I am not getting any guide how to set up.

How to set up ThingsBoard as a individual micro service inside AWS EKS>?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a guide [Installing ThingsBoard using Docker (Linux or Mac OS)](https://thingsboard.io/docs/user-guide/install/docker/). You can use this and create your own Docked image and use is inside Kubernetes.

ThingsBoard also have dedicated [Docker Hub](https://hub.docker.com/u/thingsboard), so you can use already created images.

You can use the GitHub to find [ThinkBoard Kubernetes deployments](https://github.com/thingsboard/thingsboard/tree/master/k8s).

As for the guide on how to install it on Kubernetes you could use this [Installing ThingsBoard using Kubernetes (on Google Cloud Platform) **v1.4**](http://v14.thingsboard.io/docs/user-guide/install/kubernetes/).